# Cast UInt32 to Generic T: Numeric

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I am writing a generic (numeric) class and need to cast a Uint32 result (from `arc4random()`) to the generic T. T is restricted to be Numeric. How could this be done?

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of e generic type.

Comment: Are you aware of the new [Random APIs in Swift 4.2](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md#random-api)?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the answer? Please let me know if there are problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `Numeric` protocol has an [`init?(exactly:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric/2886795-init) failable initializer which takes a `BinaryInteger` argument. If `T` conforms to `Numeric` then you can do

```
guard let val = T(exactly: arc4random()) else {
    // Handle error ...
}
```

As Alexander mentioned, you might want to take advantage of the new random APIs, e.g.

```
guard let val = T(exactly: UInt32.random(in: 0..<100)) else {
    // Handle error ...
}
```